# Proving that a 4th degree polynomial function has four fixed points and finding those fixed points

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, fixed-points

So I have this function: $g(x)=-\mu^3x^4+2\mu^3x^3-\mu^2(\mu+1)x^2+\mu^2x$ where $\mu \in [0, 4]$ and $x\in[0, 1]$. Mu is a constant parameter. I have to prove that this function has 4 fixed points and I have to calculate them which means finding them without numerical methods. I have no idea how to proceed for both of these questions so I was hoping maybe someone here could guide me. So far I was thinking that since $g(x) = x$ I could subtract x on both sides and obtain a function that is equal to zero and then show that the function has 4 zeros because it is a 4th degree polynomial but I am not sure about that. As for the fixed points, other than x=0 I don't know how I can find them, because I don't know how to factor this polynomial or the one obtained by dividing by x and subtracting by 1. Also, I have to prove that $g(x) \in [0, 1]$ for the ranges I gave earlier for $x$ and $\mu$. I tried using the derivative to find the max value of the function but once again I am stuck with a third degree polynomial.

I would be very grateful if anyone could help or at least point me in the right direction, I am totally stuck on this problem. Thanks

Comment: $x=0$ is one of them

Comment: And a polynomial of degree $N$ has $N$ roots. But in this case you need to prove that they are all real.

Comment: Hint: $g(x)-x$ has another linear factor besides $x$. Try looking for another nice root the way you would use the rational root theorem to look for a nice root of a polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: Not sure if this helps ? But the graph ... https://www.desmos.com/calculator/eg5qwmgn2j

Comment: @GregMartin Oh right I forgot I could use polynomial division to factor the polynomial once I find a root. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For the mentioned range for $\mu$, it is not true that you always have four fixed points... For instance,

- If $\mu = 1$, you have a single fixed point
- If $\mu = 2$, you have two fixed points
- If $\mu = 4$, you have four fixed points

Maybe you want to rephrase the question?

Comment: That is how the question was phrased in my homework. It is actually correctly phrased because we are studying $g_\mu$ which means it comprises every value $\mu$ can have in the chosen interval. We aren't working with $g_1$ or $g_3$.  Either way I already know what you said, I managed to find the answer to each of my questions myself.

Comment: @Samishe That is my point exactly... If you are dealing with $g_{\mu}$ for $\mu \in [0,4]$, it is not true, in general, that $g_{\mu}$ has four fixed points.

Comment: I don't think you understand. We are not working with a specific value of $\mu$. By subtracting x on both sides we get a 4th degree polynomial and a 4th degree polynomial has 4 roots which means 4 fixed points.

Comment: @Samishe This is a matter of definition. Fixed points are not counted according to their multiplicity has roots of $g_{\mu}(x) -x$. The number of fixed points is the number of **distinct** solutions of $g_{\mu}(x) = x$.

Comment: Isn't that the exact same thing? A fixed point verifies the equation $g_\mu (x) = x$ which means it must also verify the equation $g_\mu (x) - x = 0$. Both equations are equivalent...

Comment: Also, it is literally the reason why one can convert fixed points into roots and use numerical methods that are used to find roots like Newton's in order to find those fixed points. The equations are equivalent which means the number of fixed points is actually equal to the number of roots of $g_\mu (x) - x = 0$

Comment: @Samishe It is not the same... If your forth order polynomial has two real roots with multiplicity 1 and one root with multiplicity 2 (four roots, considering the multiplicities) you have 3 fixed points, not four.

Comment: @samishe that is what I am saying... A forth order polynomial may have less than 4 distinct roots, hence, there may be less than 4 fixed points. This is why the question is poorly phrased (I understand this is not your fault).

Comment: Fair enough, I understand what you mean but I can't really alter the question I was asked in the homework. However, in that case the function does have 4 distinct roots so I guess maybe that is why my teacher phrased it that way.